# Strapi filter by many to many relation

Tags: node.js, postgresql, strapi, bookshelf.js

I have two tables in postgresql in strapi: goods and labels

```
Goods:
id | title
---------
1 | some name
2 | some name 2
3 | some name 4
…………………

Labels
id | title
------------
1 | some label 1
2 | some label 2
3 | some label n
………………………
```

They are connected with each other many to many, through an additional table

```
goods_labels__labels_goods
id | good_id      | label_id
----------------------------
1  |  1           | 1
2  |  1           | 2
2  |  2           | 1
```

I need to select goods that have a relationship with both label.id = 1 and label.id = 2,  this is only the first product with id = 1. Is any way to implement it with standart strapi tools with graphql or with bookshelf, or as a last resort through a raw query?
Also I need to sort and limit this request

Comment: Have you tried _in filter? In graphql something like `{ goods(where: {label_in: [1,2]} )}`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

ok.  the content is here.

I have two content-type in strapi like tag and article. And want to filter articles which both have several tags like 1,2,4. In the standard strapi, you cannot do this .so I have to change the default behavior of strapi article api. you can find the document in [here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/controllers.html#adding-a-new-controller)

### first

we need to define the special parameter to reach our goals. in fact I choose the multiTag in the query parameter

```
query{
    multiTag: [1,2,3]   
}
```

### second

open file in your project

**/src/api/article/controllers/article.js**

! notice: the path would change with your content-type name.

you should get this

```
const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::article.article');
```

then add some code to this

```
async function getMultiTag(conn, multiTag){
    // the sql should like this 
    const sql = `
        select 
            t.id 
        from 
            article t 
        inner join (
            select article_id from article_link_tag 
            where tag_id in (${string(multiTag})
            group by article_id having count(*) = ${multiTag.length}
        )t2 on t.id = t2.article_id
    `
    const result = await conn.raw(sql)
    // result should like this 

[
    // actual data
    [
        {"id" : 1}  
    ],
  // meta info
    [
    {
        "db" : 1
    }
    ]
]

    return result[0]
}

module.exports = createCoreController('api::pet-article.pet-article', ({ strapi }) => ({
   async find(ctx) {
    ctx.query = { ...ctx.query, local: 'en' }
        // get the param
    const multiTag = ctx.query?.multiTag
    if (multiTag && typeof multiTag == 'object' && multiTag.length > 0) {
            // get the database connection
      const conn = strapi.db.connection
      const articles = await getMultiTag(conn, multiTag)
            // when you have got the ids of article 
            // you can do many things
            // like this 
            ctx.query.filter = {
                ...(ctx.query.filter || {}),
                id: {
                    $in: articles.map(val => val.id)
                }
            }
            // or just return the ids
            // return { data: articles }
    }
    const { data, meta } = await super.find(ctx);
    meta.date = Date.now()
    return { data, meta };
  },
}));
```